# Jenkins pipeline - is it possible to checkout both a branch or a tag

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, jenkins-pipeline, git-branch

In a jenkins pipeline, using the git checkout scm syntax, is it possible to checkout both - either a branch or a tag from a remote repo in same code.

For ex -

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: '$branchortagname']], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                                 url: '$url',
                                 refspec: '+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
                                 ]]
        ])
```

The above works for a tag checkout.
Without the refspec, it works for a branch checkout.
Whats the correct syntax to use for both in same bit of code - tag and branch

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find how to set it using the full checkout setting. However, if you use just the plain checkout scm without any additional settings in a multi-branch pipeline, it will checkout a tag if you are on a tag, and a branch if you are on a branch:

```
script {
    checkout scm
 }
```